# WSO2API Manager - Error Generating Access tokens with Password Grant Type

Tags: api, wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager ,Iam using Token API and trying to generate Access tokens with User Credentials -Password Grant Type.  Using SOAP UI to make the Token API requests.Key Manager is default one along with API Manager.

But upon requesting,iam not getting Access tokens.

Instead I get below error.

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">    
<am:code/>    
<am:type>Status report</am:type>    
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>    
<am:description/>
</am:fault>
```

No exception in the console as well .

Please help in addressing this issue.

Comment: Please attach wire logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html